# Django passing the value of the form in Django-forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 2 models `WorkoutCategory` and `workout` with a ForeignKey with workout_Category in `catig`

in my template i have a collapsed div "WorkoutCategory" include a collapse form "to save in `workout`model

the question is how I should pass the catig_id if it's not included in the form

below screenshot to simplify my idea

[collapsed div for woroutcategory and the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQgoe.png)

models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class WorkoutCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Workout(models.Model):
catig = models.ForeignKey(WorkoutCategory,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
workout_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
video_link = models.CharField(max_length=300)

def __str__(self):
    return self.workout_name
```

the Form:

```
from django.forms import *
from .models import *
from django import forms


class CreateWorkoutForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Workout
    exclude = ['catig']
    widgets = {
    'workout_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Workout Name'}),
    'video_link' : forms.URLInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'https://www.youtube.com/ ...'}),

    }
```

the Template:

```
{% for catg in allcetgs %}
<br>
<div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse"    href="#multiCollapseExample{{catg.id}}" role="button" aria- expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample{{catg.id}}">
        {{catg.name}}</div>
 <div class="row">
<div class="col">

  <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample{{catg.id}}">
    <div class="col">
        <br>
        <div class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" href="#addingworkout{{catg.id}}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="addingworkout{{catg.id}}" style="float: right;">add workout</div>
        <br>            <br>

    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="addingworkout{{catg.id}}" >
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{workoutForm.workout_name}}
                </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    {{workoutForm.video_link}}
                </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Workout Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Youtube Link</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for wkout in catg.workout_set.all %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{wkout.workout_name}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{wkout.video_link}}">check video</a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

I don't want the user it set the catig_id since it's already the parent div of the form. how should I pass that `catig_id` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You don't need to exclude the catig field in your form

class CreateWorkoutForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Workout
    widgets = {
    'workout_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Workout Name'}),
    'video_link' : forms.URLInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'https://www.youtube.com/ ...'}),

    }

# you can have the value of catig_id in the hidden input

<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="addingworkout{{catg.id}}" value="{{catg.id}}">
    <form id="addingworkout">
        <div class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" name="catig" value="{{catg.id}}">
            <div class="col">
                {{workoutForm.workout_name}}
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                {{workoutForm.video_link}}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey Mukul, thank you for the hint. the problem is I'm getting multiple forms since I'm using loop for the forms.  kinky check my code in the template after I edit it